# Force Chrome to open URLs as URLs, instead of searching

Tags: google-chrome, webserver, hosts-file

I have a local Apache server running, which is defined through `/etc/hosts` as "apache". So I often open pages like:

```
http://apache/website/
```

Normally, this works fine. However, since I am using a more recent Chrome browser, at odd moments the browser decides that the URL I type is not a URL but actually a search, so it loads my default search engine and tries to find this URL. It often, but not always, shows a link under the address bar that says `Did you mean to go to http://apache/website?`. That is nice, but very annoying having to click here instead of going there directly. What makes Chrome behave this way? Can I fix this?

Comment: [Asked the same question for Brave](https://superuser.com/questions/1696611/force-brave-to-open-urls-as-urls-instead-of-searching).

Answer (score 65):

I had the same problem and i found that typing the / at the end will always treat it as a url instead of keyword.

For example in my case :

```
local.dev/ben is treated as search
```

but

```
local.dev/ben/ its working fine
```

Comment: Saying that appending a / at the end will always treat it as a url instead of a keyword does not always hold true, for example scoped link local addresses will trigger a search even if a / is present: `https://[fe80::1%eth0]/`

Comment: Does not work for my improved nodejs server `http://0.0.0.0:8080/bla/` Does not work!

Comment: @hitautodestruct 0.0.0.0 is not a valid ip address, it's a placeholder address that generally means default route in routing, or all ipv4 addresses on the host for services. You would need to reach it via a valid ip address assigned to your host.

Answer (score 39):

You can implicitly do this by creating a new search engine with a URL of `http://%s` and keyword of `null`. Then, set this as the default search engine.

To get to the search engines page in chrome:

- Open `Settings` panel.
- Click `Manage search engines...` button under `Search` heading.
- `Search Engines` pane has two sections: `Default search engines` and `Other search engines`
- At the bottom of the `Other search engines` section, you'll see a form which we'll make use to add a new search engine.

[image: Search Engines]

Comment: That's a neat trick. I'll have to try it out!

Comment: @iglvzx Thanks, but this only works if I _always_ want to open any keyword this way. I really like to keep using Google Search when typing other words, but I just don't want this to happen when I am typing a localhost URL.

Comment: It's no longer possible to set 'null' as keyword as of Chrome v26.

Comment: @skolima It's possible in v27.0

Comment: @svandragt: v27 is now stable and unfortunately this is still disabled. Crap.

Comment: Update as of Chrome v33: you can add the "null" keyword, but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: I used "htp://localhost/%s%", thinking that that would save a DNS lookup and get a "This web page is not available" result sooner.  Does that make sense? (I actually used http, not htp, but this page would display it as a link instead of just text.  I don't know how to display an URL as text).  Thanks for a solution to this annoyance.

Comment: This works, but Chrome keeps adding a freaky trailing slash `/` to all urls. Chrome should burn in hell!

Answer (score 14):

I got annoyed by this as well. I recently found out what caused it. Try disabling 'Use a web service to help resolve navigation errors'.

[image]

Comment: This does not work if I then add to the URL. e.g. I load local.symphony-2.3 and then add /symphony or /symphony/ to the URL, chrome searches google for that phrase.

Comment: In Chrome 54 this is in "Show Advanced Settings" on the bottom of `about://settings` page.

Answer (score 3):

In latest chrome settings - Advanced settings

[image]

Comment: Rik supplied this answer six years before you did: https://superuser.com/a/394874/84181

Comment: Rik's answer is seven years out of date.  Mohamed Alikhan provides an updated screenshot from the newer version of the browser and that's very helpful in my opinion.

Comment: this feature is no more exist in todays chrome

Answer (score 2):

If you know the port you're using, you can specify it by hand like

> url:80/index.html

instead of

> url/index.html

In the first case, it won't be treated as a search request

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome 69 even using :80

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to disable the ability to make searches from the address bar (omnibox) of Google Chrome:

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Type `chrome://flags` in the address bar and press Enter.
3. Scroll to *Enable search button in Omnibox*.
4. Select *Disabled*.

Comment: I don't have this option; what version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add google.co.in with the search string: http://google.com/search?q=%s to get both Google Search and URL search working.

Now if I want to browse URL I can just append 'http://whatever' and choose if i want to do a URL navigation or search.

@iglvzx's answer no longer seems to work in version 40 of Chrome. It looks like Null is not a valid entry anymore. I had to improvise as above to get this working.

Comment: Hmm not working for me on Chrome 40. What an odd bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Chrome on my Android phone. I resolved it similar to @Rik suggestion.

For **mobile Chrome**:

1. Go to **Settings** -> **Privacy**
2. Untick **Navigation error suggestions**

Comment: i had to untick "navigation error suggestions" and "search and site suggestions" (the first two options) before chrome stopped turning my urls to search queries. afterwards i could enable both settings and chrome still opened my urls as it should. bad chrome. bad propietary black box chrome. i am using firefox kthxbye

Answer (score 0):

Try add correct url to browser bookmarks. Then Chrome suggests this address on the first place (marked with star).

[image: chrome omnibox]

Comment: It's unusual to have a hostname as short as a single character. Chrome is suggesting file:/// because a: is a drive letter. Same if you typed "c:\Users\", "a:81" is a file named "81" on the "a" drive. This is of course assuming your using Windows.

Comment: I do not recommend domain 'a', it is just proof that it works. Because i think that complete disable search from address line is not good solution. But good point.