# How do I make Chrome accept ".test" as a valid TLD?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, search, url, tld

When I enter, say, `xyz.test` in the Chrome address bar, then Chrome initiates a search. How do I make Chrome *always* treat `.test` as a top level domain, just like `.com` and all the others?

I know that I can just put `http://` in front, but I tend to forget that, especially when editing an address that has already been entered. By the way, that's another annoyance: I would like to have Chrome always show the `http://` in the address bar.

Comment: Part of that question overlaps [at least one existing SuperUser question](http://superuser.com/questions/354338/).

Comment: No overlap: The user who posted the question enters `http://`. I don't want to enter `http://` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that the [iglvzx's proposal](https://superuser.com/questions/354338/force-chrome-to-open-urls-as-urls-instead-of-searching/354344#354344), sent in reply to another user's inquiry, offers a partial workaround:

> You can implicitly do this by creating a new search engine with a URL of `http://%s` and keyword of `null`. Then, set this as the default search engine.

I say *partial workaround* since now the default search functionality in the address bar is entirely disabled. For the time being, I marked my answer as accepted. But I may change that, if someone offers a better solution!