# How to disable search in the Google Chrome address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force Chrome to open URLs as URLs, instead of searching](https://superuser.com/questions/354338/force-chrome-to-open-urls-as-urls-instead-of-searching)

I'm surprised that I haven't found this question on superuser.  Forgive me if it's a duplicate, but how do you disable the search functionality in Google Chrome's address bar?

I want it to be just a straight up address bar.  I know the address where I want to go.  I don't want to have to click the "did you mean to go to" link all the time when Chrome thinks the word I typed is more likely to be a search term than a server.  You'd think putting the http:// in front would help, but I already do this by default anyway and no dice. =/

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't disable the search feature of the Omnibox.

You can disable instant search by clicking the wrench > options > basic  and unchecking "enable instant."

A possible work around is to create a custom search engine for chrome. Right click in the Omnibox (search bar) and choose Edit search engines.  You can create a blank search engine that will always fail by putting "no" "null" and "http://%s" in the Name, Keyword, and URL fields respectively.

If you're trying to point this to a local host, you could potentially use the URL field for this, though I have not tried this, and cannot confirm.

Comment: Okay.  Is there a way to make Chrome aware of the servers I have set up in my hosts file?

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on what you want to do. I've edited my answer to provide some more details and a possible work around.

Comment: Wow excellent.  Works perfectly.  Note that %s (without the http:// prefix) in the URL field works better for me because I might be visiting URLs using different protocols.

Comment: Nice, that worked just fine. I created a dummy custom search engine (`Null   Null   null://%s`) and set it as the default. Now typing a basic string does nothing. (It would have been easier, cleaner, and more versatile if they had not removed the ability to create engines without `%s` or containing JavaScript. ಠ_ಠ)