# How to type in Google Chrome's New Tab Page in Full Screen Mode

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fullscreen, address-bar, omnibox

For me, Chrome's "new tab page" doesn't work in full screen mode, in the sense that my typing has no effect - the omnibox and the search box seem dead. Clicking on the omnibox to give it focus has no effect either. I am forced to come back out of full screen, do my search, navigate away fro the "new tab page", and then go fullscreen. This is very irritating as I open new tabs while in full screen mode all the time. Over several versions of Chrome, I haven't see this reported, let alone fixed.

Note that when not in full screen mode, the typing starts in the search box in the middle of the "new tab page" but jumps to the Omnibox. I'm sure this feature is related to the problem.

Also note that this "new tab page" isn't the google home page - it looks a bit like it but it's different. it's a page locally generated by the browser and personalised for your profile. I've done some testing and the issue persists while not logged in to the profile.

Note that I have searched for questions on this problem but haven't found it reported. There are lots of similar sounding issues, but these are all different.

Any sensible suggestions are more than welcome.

Thank you!

This is a very similar issue:
[Disable address bar search in Google Chrome at www.google.com](https://superuser.com/questions/683574/disable-address-bar-search-in-google-chrome-at-www-google-com?newreg=99c0fd03bc754b49ad3a669f9717d9d2)

Versions:
Browser: Google Chrome {79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)} 
OS: macOS Mojave {10.14.6}

Comment: Have you tried enabling : chrome://flags/#ntp-realbox