# How to force Google Chrome's omnibar to treat an rdp://-prefixed URL as a URL

Tags: google-chrome, browser, url

I am currently using [this RDP Hyperlink solution](http://www.jjclements.co.uk/2010/02/21/rdp-hyperlink/) to run windows remote desktop by clicking a hyperlink or typing a URL into a browser/explorer.

Unfortunately, Chrome treats URLs beginning in `rdp://` as strings and searches for it.

I am specifically interested in a way of modifying the string so that Chrome treats it as a hyperlink. I am less interested in changing settings of the browser, as I would like to implement this on multiple devices. Alternatively, I guess I could change the script of the solution to find a different prefix, beginning in `http://` but it seems Chrome is the only browser with this particular problem.

[Adding a slash to the end of the URL](https://superuser.com/a/454785/390577) did not help.

Comment: @DavidPostill I already know that one can launch RDP via URL. And I have. I am looking for a solution to the Chrome issue.