# How to add exceptions to Google Chrome's automatic searching from the URL bar?

Tags: google-chrome

As a developer, I would like Google Chrome to refrain from automatically searching a particular URL typed in the address bar. This is because my `hosts` file has entries such as `local.mysite` which I'm resolving as a local host and don't want Google Chrome to interpret for its search engine.

Is there an exceptions list in Chrome that I could add this address to?

Answer (score 0):

While my knowledge of Chrome is admittedly limited, I don't believe there is such a list currently.

I am relatively certain your basic options would be:

- Consistently use a `/` at the end of your local addresses (this would be aided by bookmarking).
- Disable the Omnibox search function (which, from casual observation, doesn't seem to present itself as a clear option in Chrome 63).
- Create a custom search engine entry to (temporarily) intercept searches.

*Creating A Custom Search Engine*

[Per an answer to this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/a/354344/302907), it is possible to create a custom search engine entry in Chrome that effectively bypasses the search feature of the Omnibox. The steps for the current version of Chrome on Windows (Chrome 63) are as follows:

- Open the "Settings" page via the three vertical dots in the upper right corner of the
  browser.
- Scroll down to "Manage search engines" and click the right-facing arrow.
- Under the "Other search engines" list, click "ADD" on the right.
- In the form for the new search engine entry, type any name you wish in the "Search engine" field, enter `null` in the "Keyword" field, and use `http://` and then `%s` in the "URL" field.
- Click "Save" when finished.

*ex. Custom Search Engine To Bypass Omnibox Searches*
[image: Omnibox Custom Search Example]

*Finishing Touches*

Note that the new search engine listing will appear under "Other search engines" but will not be initially available for Omnibox ("address bar") searches (which requires it to be listed under the "Default search engines"). You must click the three vertical dots to right of the new entry and select "Make default". The new entry will move the to the "Default search engines" list and can be toggled as default from then on.

*Caveats*

The big drawback to this approach is that normal searches via the Omnibox will not work while your custom search engine is active (i.e. typing "How do I do blah?" in the Omnibox will not take you to e.g. Google anymore).

That said, switching the default search engine, creating a simple bookmark to e.g. Google or using a second (differently configured) browser are all arguably easy remedies to this issue.